# ajax поиск по xml файлу

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, search

Здравствуйте. У меня следующая задача. Нужно с помощью  и jquery реализовать поиск по xml. Чтобы когда человек начинал вводить в инпут текст, тут же в выпадающем списке под инпутом отображались нужные ему варианты. У объектов в xml есть имя (title) и ссылка (url). Соответственно, чтобы в выдаче было только название объекта и при клике по нему был переход на соответствующий url.

Извините если запутанно объяснил, отвечу на все вопросы и предоставлю код если нужно. Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так, если не видеть код. Но принцип должен быть понятен

```
var parser = new DOMParser(),
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(ajaxResponse,"text/xml");

var url = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("url")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```